# get_document_topics() returns empty list of topics

Tags: gensim

I am having a 1-word document that I want to transform to its bag-of-words representation:

so `doc` is `['party']` and `id2word.doc2bow(doc)` is `[(229, 1)]` which means the word is known.

However, if I call `get_document_topics()` with `doc_bow`, the result is an *empty* list:

```py
id2word = lda.id2word 

# ..

doc_bow = id2word.doc2bow(doc)

t = lda.get_document_topics(doc_bow)

try:
    label, prob = sorted(t, key=lambda x: -x[1])[0]
except Exception as e:
    print('Error!')
    raise e
```

The only possible explanation I'd have here is that this document (the single word) cannot be assigned to *any* topic. Is this the reason why I am seeing this?

Comment: I suspect by modifying the parameter minimum_probability and setting it to a very small value like say 0.000001 you should be able to get a non-empty list. This parameter determines the min probability of a topic. Let's say if the word "party" is associated with topic 1 with a probability 0.0001 do you want to output it or no?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this issue:

in the file gensim/models/ldamodel.py you need to edit value of epsilon to a larger value.

```
DTYPE_TO_EPS = {
    np.float16: 1e-5,
    np.float32: 1e-35, #line to change 
    np.float64: 1e-100,
}
```

also, make sure to set the minimum_probability parameter of get_document_topics to a very small value.